Is $\operatorname{ECLIQUE}$ in $\Pi_2^p$?
I was watching this lecture on the Polynomial hierarchy and one of the presented examples was the language \begin{equation*}
    \operatorname{ECLIQUE} = \{ \langle G, k \rangle \; : \; G \text{ is a graph in which the largest clique is of size } k\}
\end{equation*}
I understand that $\operatorname{ECLIQUE}$ presumably does not belong to $\operatorname{NP} = \Sigma_1^p$ because there are no apparent short witness to whether $G$ has the maximum clique of exactly the size $k$. Analogously $\operatorname{ECLIQUE} \not \in \operatorname{co-NP} = \Pi_1^p$ (most likely). But $\operatorname{ECLIQUE} \in \Sigma_2^p$ because \begin{equation*}
    x \in \operatorname{ECLIQUE}  \iff \exists^{p(|x|)} u_1 \; \forall^{p(|x|)} u_2 \; \; V(x,u_1,u_2) = 1
\end{equation*}
where $V$ accepts only if $x = \langle G, k \rangle$, $u_1$ represents a clique of size $k$ in $G$ and $u_2$ does not represent a clique of size $k+1$.
My question is: does $\operatorname{ECLIQUE}$ belong to $\Pi_2^p$? Can one swith the quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$ in the above expression? It seem to me that it is true because $u_2$ does not depend on $u_1$, but I'm not sure. If it is not the case could you please give a simple exemple of a language (preferably derived from the graph theory) that is in $\Sigma_2^p \cap \Pi_2^p$ but (most likely) does not belong to $\operatorname{NP} \cup \operatorname{co-NP}$?

Let
$$\def\clq{\mathrm{CLIQUE}}\def\p#1{\langle#1\rangle}
\clq=\{\p{G,k}:\text{$G$ has a clique of size $k$}\}.$$
Then
$$\p{G,k}\in\mathrm{ECLIQUE}\iff\p{G,k}\in\clq\land\p{G,k+1}\notin\clq,$$
hence the problem belongs to the class DP, which is included in $\Delta^P_2$. (It is also included in BH and in $\Theta^P_2$.)

Thanks!
Is there a way to tweak somehow $\operatorname{ECLIQUE}$ so that it remains in $\Sigma^p_2$ but does not belong to $\Pi_2^p$?

That’s too vague a question.

I want to get a better understanding of the polynomian hierarchy so I'm looking for a language from $\Sigma_2^p \setminus \Pi_2^p$ (assuming $\operatorname{PH}$ doesn't collapse) other than $\operatorname{QBF}_2$, preferably from the graph theory (because it's easier for me to understand this kind of languages).
